# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'; rhel8; python3; apache2.4; mod_wsgi; django 3.1

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache, mod-wsgi, rhel8

Am trying to setup my django application (virtual environment) using apache and mod_wsgi. the application is running on RHEL8 machine and the only python running is python 3.

RHEL version == Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.2 (Ootpa)

python version == Python 3.6.8.

apache version == Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux).

mod_wsgi version == 4.7.1.

django version == 3.1.

My Python virtual environment home is:
[python-home using sys.prefix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/293Xx.png)

i have created the mod_wsgi.so using CMMI method. below is the library detail

ldd mod_wsgi.so [details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPQdp.png)

below is my virtual host conf file for apache.
i have also tried adding python-path (like below), although not written in conf file details below.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess sohail python-home=/home/ilearn/webapps/sohail python-path=/home/ilearn/webapps/sohail/src
```

webapptest.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

WSGIScriptAlias /webapptest /home/ilearn/webapps/sohail/src/webapptraining/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess sohail python-home=/home/ilearn/webapps/sohail

WSGIProcessGroup sohail
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}


<Directory /home/ilearn/webapps/sohail/src/webapptraining>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

As soon as i startup my apache server i see the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'` in error logs.

```
[core:notice] [pid 4576:tid 139861315184960] AH00052: child pid 4893 exit signal Aborted (6)
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

appreciate any help or advise to resolve the problem.

thanks.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm seeing the same problem and would love a clue.